# Why are there no logstash indexes in kibana

Tags: indexing, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I set up ELK stack and filebeat with my ELK node as a RedHat server following the digitalocean tutorial. Kibana is up and running, but I dont see any logstash indexes when I go to configure an index pattern as logstash-*:

```
Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have any indices matching the pattern?
```

When I do a curl to see the indexes I have, they are only filebeat indexes. Filebeat should be pushing data to logstash which is listening on 5044

```
$curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
health status index               pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   filebeat-2017.01.10   5   1       3864            0      1.7mb          1.7mb 
yellow open   filebeat-2017.06.17   5   1       1848            0    740.1kb        740.1kb 
yellow open   filebeat-2017.01.18   5   1      77062            0       33mb           33mb 
yellow open   filebeat-2017.09.14   5   1       1932            0      1.1mb          1.1mb 
yellow open   filebeat-2017.01.11   5   1      19094            0      3.6mb          3.6mb 
yellow open   .kibana
```

You can see I only have filebeat indexes. I checked my ports are open, and My config files are correct according to the tutorial. What could be wrong? Filebeat should be sending logs from /var/log/*.log to logstash, to elasticsearch.

When I

```
tail /var/log/logstash/logstash.log
```

there is nothing in my logstash log. I've checked and logstash, filebeat, kibana, and elasticsearch are all running. Ive also done the config file test and it said it was OK:

```
$sudo service logstash status
logstash is running
```

On my ELK node, I can clearly see the port 5044 is listening:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep -i listen | grep -v tcp6
 tcp        0      0 :::5044                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filebeat creates daily indices using a pattern of `filebeat-YYYY.MM.dd` so you should not expect to see logstash indices in Elasticsearch.

The [Logstash configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/5.1/logstash-installation.html#logstash-setup) recommended in the Filebeat documentation writes the data to an index based on `"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"` where `[@metadata][beat]` defaults to the name of the beat (filebeat) unless `output.logstash.index` is configured in the Filebeat config. Here's the base configuration for Logstash.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }   
}   

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }   
}
```

You can inspect the data in those indices to see if it's what you are expected to get from filebeat with a command like:

`curl http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_search?pretty&size=100`

Answer (score 1):

Did you [define](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html#tutorial-define-index) your index in your `Kibana`, from **Management > Index Patterns > Add New**?

It's obvious that you won't be able to find the index which you've created using `logstash` in Kibana, unless you're manually creating it there within the `Managemen` section of `Kibana`.

Make sure, that you have the same name of the indice which you created using `logstash`. Have a look at the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html), which conveys:

> When you define an index pattern, indices that match that pattern must
>   exist in Elasticsearch. Those indices must contain data.

which pretty much says that the indice should exist for you to create the index in `Kibana`. What `logstash` does is, to only create the indices in `Elasticsearch` itself, where as you have to manually create them in `Kibana` in order to access the and visualize the data.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, so I guess the right question for me to ask was, why are there no logstash indices in my elasticsearch?

Comment: How're you creating the indice? Using `logstash` or using a `curl` request?

Comment: I am defining my index pattern under the Add New section in Kibana interface, I type in logstash-* in the text field. I didn't define any indices, as they should already be there in logstash sent over from filebeat.

Comment: No you have type in your indice's name which is `filebeat-*` so that it'll list down your indices. logstash-* is just there as a default indice. As you can see there, `logstash-*` is just an example.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response again Darth_Vader. I understand that there are filebeat indices that exist, but shouldn't those be logstash indices, since filebeat sends the logs to logstash to process and index the logs? I am able to create the filebeat-* index pattern and view data in those filebeat indices.

Comment: @Celestemanughian-peter Oops i'm sorry, haven't worked with `filebeat` personally. If you can show your `logstash` conf, could add some hint!